# How to register rss for a website?

Tags: wordpress, website

I am not sure if I ask this question in the right place, because I am new to it. What I want to ask is, do I need to register/create RSS for my website?

I have a website, lets say:

[http://blog.domain.com] => its a 2.9.2 wordpress blog

So, if I want to display the latest content in another subdomain, for example: [news.domain.com], how do I do that? I know a little bit of php and mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to generate an RSS feed from a WordPress blog. That's built in. Not sure what you mean by "register"?

As for your last paragraph: You want to display content from blog A on blog B. Where? In the sidebar of blog B? Use the built-in RSS Widget as that's exactly what it is for. Or do you mean you want the posts from Blog A to show up as Posts on Blog B? Then you'll want to find a syndication plugin ([here's a search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=syndication&sort=) on the WordPress plugins page). FeedWordPress used to be the de facto standard for this stuff but I've lost track if it is still updated. I'm sure you can find another if not.

Hope that all helps.

Side note: WordPress support forum can be found at http://wordpress.org/support

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is a plugin or module that generates a RSS feed for a website if using a framework. Then all that needs to be done is to add an appropriate `<link>` element to the web page's header in order to notify the browser about the availability of a feed.

If you are talking about *consuming* a feed, then some web frameworks have modules available that will read a given feed and generate HTML for the articles contained within.